# Alternative to waiting in a method with a while loop

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program that runs through my method possibly 50 times a second or more (necessary)

The method needs to follow this model:

- Create boolean value.
- Wait until the value changes.
- Continue on in the method.

Simple, I know, but I don't want to use a `while` loop because it takes up 3% or so CPU more than it should, and I imagine, should I need it to wait any longer for the value to change, that could take up all of my CPU cycles, which I don't want. Also, creating a new thread for every time I execute the method at 50 times per second is a horrible idea.

So what could I do? If I need to provide any other kind of information feel free to ask.

Comment: How is the boolean value going to get changed? Are you in control of the code doing the changing?

Comment: Don’t use a boolean value. Research a bit on how to use an [`EventWaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) instead (or maybe someone will post you an example).

Comment: Here is a good resource for multithreading http://www.albahari.com/threading/ Concentrate on signalling section.

Comment: The value gets passed to another method via a ref and when it's done it returns true @minitech And douglas, I'll look into it.

Comment: Can you write example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Could a `ManualResetEvent` be of any use?  Not sure how it would work with your system, but it might be something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of the method, you could just make the rest of the method into an event handler, and the place that changes its value then first a ValueChanged type event.